# How to completely delete Instagram account?

Tags: privacy, account-management, instagram

I deleted my Instagram account yesterday (in their website), all my photos are deleted, and I can't sign in to my account anymore, but my account still exists, all followers and following pages still visible to visitors, and as I didn't signed out of account from my android phone, I still can post photos and even send/receive direct messages, and get followers!

As I said, I can not sign in to my account from instagram.com and it says "Your username or password was incorrect.", I can not recover password and it says "Sorry, this user is not active.". Also my Edit Profile page don't loads in android app...

I have real privacy issues, I added my phone number in edit profile page under private information(or something like this?), but it seems that Instagram sends notification to those that I'm in their phone contacts and said that I'm on Instagram.

I also sent an form on their help center, but they never answered me after 24 hours.

Comment: Most likely because it takes a little time for cached data to be refreshed. I expect everything will be gone within a day or two. Unfortunately, the [Instagram Help page on deleting an account](https://help.instagram.com/448136995230186/) makes no mention of how long it takes for an account to completely disappear.

Comment: Thanks @AlE. You were right, after 48 hours and filling contact form for 2 times, they finally deleted that account. I believe it's a shame, sharing a large photo takes no time, but deleting account which needs a single flag byte and is an emergency action, needs 48 hours. Anyway, thank you.