# How do I Bulk Delete all of my Instagram Comments and Replies?

Tags: instagram

How do I Bulk Delete all of my Instagram Comments and Replies?
For facebook I found a GitHub open source program that deletes all of my activity sorted (I can filter) wonderfully.
I want a script for Instagram to bulk delete my activity for privacy sake.

Comment: Related: [How to completely delete Instagram account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87314/197614) (from someone who already managed to delete all their posts.)

Comment: I want to delete comments only the whole account